# Android Studio. Почему во вкладке Problems не отображаются все ошибки и предупреждения?

Tags: android, android-studio

При запуске проверки кода через **Code -> Inspect code**, отображаются только эти ошибки, хотя проект содержит и другие предупреждения.
[image: Ошибки, которые распознаются]

Окно настроек **Inspection Scope**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта ошибка не отображается при поиске во всём проекте, а только во вкладке **Current File**.
[image: Ошибка, которая не отображается]

[image: Вкладка Current File]

При этом в настройках она включена для поверки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что за фильтр включен на первом скрине?

Comment: Filter resolved items (фильтровать решённые элементы). Если какую либо ошибку исправить, то она сразу уберётся из этого списка.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема. Поэтому я инспектировал код отдельно для каждого модуля. Причём делал я это нажав правой кнопкой мыши по самому модулю и выбрал: Analize -> Inspect Code... -> Directory [Название модуля] -> OK
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, мне это не помогло

Comment: Помогло обновление IDE

Answer (score 0):

Помогло обновление IDE с версии Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2 до версии Dolphin 2021.3.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]